# Get exception details from lightning:flow

Tags: visual-workflow

I'm firing a flow straight from Lightning component.

However I am not able to find a way to display any meaningful exceptions to user...

So far I've tried in change handler:

```
event.getParam('outputVariables')
event.getParam('error')
event.getParam('errors')
event.getParam('FaultMessage')
event.getParams()
```

Wondering if I query it somehow via guid that's returned? I don't have much hope.